# $_POST does not work on the server

Tags: php, post

I tried to make a little form which worked fine. But as I wanted to test it on my server It just doesn't save the values.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

returns:

```
array(4) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["pass"]=> string(0) "" ["e-mail"]=> string(0) "" ["register"]=> string(12) "registieren!" }
```

on my local server, but

```
array(0) { }
```

on my normal server.

```
enable_post_data_reading
```

is "on" on both.

Does anyone have ideas?

Edit:

I think I got the error.
phpinfo()
returns:

```
REQUEST_METHOD  POST
```

on my local server and

```
REQUEST_METHOD  GET
```

on my webserver. How can I change this - I didn't find any useful stuff

Here is more code:

```
        define('URL', 'http://localhost/');
        define('WEBSITE_NAME', 'Project/');
        define('URLGAME', 'u/');
        define('LANG', 'en/');
```

Here is the form which doesn't work:

```
<form method="post" action="'.URL.WEBSITE_NAME.LANG.URLGAME.'register">
```

In the browser it looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost/Project/en/u/register">
```

It is the same stuff on my server, but with those definitions:

```
        define('URL', 'http://yangidu.de/');
        define('WEBSITE_NAME', 'yang/');
        define('URLGAME', 'u/');
        define('LANG', 'en/');
```

And in the browser it looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="http://yangidu.de/yang/en/u/register">
```

This is the button (Same on both versions):

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="register" value="registieren!" />
```

If I type in:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

it returns

```
array(4) { ["name"]=> string(3) "asd" ["pass"]=> string(3) "asd" ["e-mail"]=> string(3) "asd" ["register"]=> string(12) "registieren!" }
```

on my local server, but

array(0) { }

on my server.

I *think* that the error is because the REQUEST_METHOD is not the same.
(I got it with phpinfo())
On my local server it's:

```
REQUEST_METHOD  POST
```

And on my server it's:

```
REQUEST_METHOD      GET
```

Comment: Could you give `echo file_get_contents('php://input');` a try, see if that prints anything out(which will help us ensure PHP is aware of any post data at all).

Comment: It returns nothing, but take a look at my post - I found the error but I don't know how to fix it^^

Comment: That's likely to do with your form, not the server. Could you show the form opening tag.

Comment: <form action="'.URL.WEBSITE_NAME.LANG.URLGAME.'register" method="post">

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing wrong in the expanded version of the form element?  In other words what your browser gets when you load the form.

Comment: But if there would be something wrong, then it wouldn't work on my local server I guess

Comment: That would depend on the values of `URL`, `WEBSITE_NAME`, `LANG`, and `URLGAME`

Comment: They're set to the same value for both local and remote tests?  If they're not the same, try to put your `method` attribute before your `action` attribute to avoid the possibility of the constant values messing things up.  If that at least fixes what php reports for `REQUEST_METHOD` in `phpinfo()`, I would examine the `form` element more carefully.

Comment: They're at the same value... ._. the only things changing are URL, WEBSITE_NAME, LANG, and URLGAME

Comment: I would move this discussion to chat, but your reputation is not high enough.  Anyway, I think you're missing my point.  I know that the value of `method` is the same in both cases - it's hard coded.  We're trying to rule out the possibility of the value of the constants making `action` malformed which could "bleed" into `method`.  If you move `method` before `action`, `method` will be parsed first.  Give it a shot... or show us the constant values and/or the expanded `form` elements for both cases.

Comment: I tried it out... It didn't work :/
Localhost: 
define('URL', 'http://localhost/');
define('WEBSITE_NAME', 'project/');
define('URLGAME', 'u/');
define('LANG', 'de');
on The webserver everything is the same except:
define('URL', 'http://yangidu.de/');
define('WEBSITE_NAME', 'yang/');

Localhost:
<form action="http://localhost/project/de/u/register" method="post">
webserver:
<form action="http://yangidu.de/yang/de/u/register" method="post">

The form is in both cases the same... A few types of input like this:
<input id="name" col="30" type="text" name="name"/>

Comment: It doesn't look malformed.  I assume that's not the actual output - there's no protocol in your `action`, e.g. `action="http://..."`.  With no protocol it would be seen as a relative path.  I assume `LANG` is `de/` not `de`, and that you have `yangidu.de` in your `hosts` file - it doesn't resolve for me.  Having a `;` is unusual, but I doubt that's causing the issue since it's there in both cases.  What browser are you testing on?  Try the Network tab in the dev tools (usually the `F12` key).  I'd really like to help more, but I'm flying blind.  Can you post your actual code in your question?

Comment: I added a few more informations on my question, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 2):

I got the error:
This webserver redirected me everytime and because of this the $_POST got lost.
Now I changed the action="" to the "real" source of the website and because of that the website didn't reload 2 times.

Anyway thank you for your help guys!

Comment: Sorry I got pulled away the other day and just remembered to come back to see if I could be of any further help.  I'm glad you found your solution :D

Answer (score 0):

Check the method attribute on the opening form tag. It should be post:

```
<form method="post" action="/some/url">
```

Comment: It is post <form action="'.URL.WEBSITE_NAME.LANG.URLGAME.'register" method="post">